# test.service_container error when id do phpunit tests

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit, api-platform.com

I have an application with API Platorm (v3)
and i made some tests but when I do a php bin/phpunit I have this error :

[image: Error]

So after that I tried to get the docker configuration from api platform (composer + caddy)
And the tests works, so maybe the error is from my docker configuration, I really don't know...

Here are some files which can be useful to found the error...

Login Test

```
<?php
    
    declare(strict_types=1);
    
    namespace App\Tests\Functional\Security;
    
    use ApiPlatform\Symfony\Bundle\Test\ApiTestCase;
    use App\Security\Domain\Entity\User;
    use Doctrine\DBAL\Connection;
    use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
    use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application;
    use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput;
    use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\NullOutput;
    use Symfony\Component\Uid\Uuid;
    
    final class LoginTest extends ApiTestCase
    {
        private static Connection|null $connection;
    
        public static function setUpBeforeClass(): void
        {
            parent::setUpBeforeClass();
    
            static::bootKernel();
    
            /** @var Connection $connection */
            $connection = static::getContainer()->get(Connection::class);
            static::$connection = $connection;
    
            (new Application(static::$kernel))
                ->find('doctrine:database:create')
                ->run(new ArrayInput(['--if-not-exists' => true]), new NullOutput())
            ;
    
            (new Application(static::$kernel))
                ->find('doctrine:schema:update')
                ->run(new ArrayInput(['--force' => true]), new NullOutput())
            ;
        }
    
        protected function setUp(): void
        {
            static::bootKernel();
            static::$connection?->executeStatement('TRUNCATE users');
        }
    
        public function testGetUser(): void
        {
            $client = static::createClient();
    
            /** @var EntityManagerInterface $em */
            $em = static::getContainer()->get(EntityManagerInterface::class);
            $repository = $em->getRepository(User::class);
    
            $user = new User(Uuid::v4(), 'user+2@email.com');
    
            $em->persist($user);
            $em->flush();
    
            $client->request('GET', sprintf('/api/users/%s', $user->id));
    
            $this->assertResponseIsSuccessful();
            $this->assertMatchesResourceItemJsonSchema(User::class);
    
            $this->assertJsonContains([
                'email' => 'user+2@email.com'
            ]);
        }
    
        public function testCreateUser(): void
        {
            $client = static::createClient();
    
            /** @var EntityManagerInterface $em */
            $em = static::getContainer()->get(EntityManagerInterface::class);
            $repository = $em->getRepository(User::class);
    
            $this->assertSame(0, $repository->count([]));
    
            $response = $client->request('POST', '/api/users', [
                'json' => [
                    'email' => 'user+1@email.com'
                ]
            ]);
    
            $this->assertResponseIsSuccessful();
            $this->assertMatchesResourceItemJsonSchema(User::class);
    
            $this->assertJsonContains([
                'email' => 'user+1@email.com'
            ]);
    
            $id = Uuid::fromString($response->toArray()['id']);
    
            $user = $repository->find($id);
    
            $this->assertNotNull($user);
            $this->assertSame('user+1@email.com', $user?->email);
        }
    }
```

Docker compose

```
    version: '3.7'
    services:
      php:
        container_name: burgu_api_php
        build: docker
        working_dir: /var/www/html
        user: '1000'
        ports:
          - "9000:8000"
        env_file:
          - .env
        depends_on:
          - database
          - mailer
        volumes:
          - .:/var/www/html
        networks:
          - default
    
      mailer:
        image: schickling/mailcatcher
        container_name: burgu_api_mailer
        ports: [ "1025", "1080" ]
        networks:
          - default
    
      database:
        image: postgres:13-alpine
        container_name: burgu_api_db
        environment:
          POSTGRES_DB: burgu_api_db
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
          POSTGRES_USER: root
        env_file:
          - .env
        volumes:
          - database:/var/lib/postgresql/data:rw
        ports:
          - "5432"
        networks:
          - default
    
      database-test:
        image: postgres:13-alpine
        container_name: burgu_api_db_test
        environment:
          POSTGRES_DB: burgu_api_db_test
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: burgu
          POSTGRES_USER: burgu
        volumes:
          - database-test:/var/lib/postgresql/data:rw
        ports:
          - "5433:5432"
    
    volumes:
      database:
      database-test:
```

Dockerfile PHP

```
FROM php:8.1-cli

RUN apt-get update \
    &&  apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        locales apt-utils git libicu-dev g++ libpng-dev libxml2-dev libzip-dev libonig-dev libxslt-dev unzip libpq-dev nodejs npm wget \
        apt-transport-https lsb-release ca-certificates sudo

RUN echo "en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8" > /etc/locale.gen  \
    &&  echo "fr_FR.UTF-8 UTF-8" >> /etc/locale.gen \
    &&  locale-gen

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- \
    &&  mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer

RUN curl -sS https://get.symfony.com/cli/installer | bash \
    &&  mv /root/.symfony5/bin/symfony /usr/local/bin/symfony

RUN docker-php-ext-configure \
            intl \
    &&  docker-php-ext-install \
            pdo pdo_mysql pdo_pgsql opcache intl zip calendar dom mbstring gd xsl

RUN pecl install apcu && docker-php-ext-enable apcu

RUN npm install --global yarn

RUN adduser www-data sudo
RUN usermod -u 1000 www-data
RUN passwd --delete www-data

RUN mkdir -p /var/cache/symfony \
    && chown -R www-data:www-data /var/cache/symfony \
    && chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www \
    && chown -R www-data:www-data /usr/local/bin/composer \
    && chown -R www-data:www-data /usr/local/bin/symfony

CMD tail -f /dev/null
```

Kernel

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Shared\Infrastructure\Symfony;

use App\Shared\Application\Command\CommandHandlerInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Kernel\MicroKernelTrait;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\Configurator\ContainerConfigurator;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel as BaseKernel;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Loader\Configurator\RoutingConfigurator;

final class Kernel extends BaseKernel
{
    use MicroKernelTrait;

    protected function configureContainer(ContainerConfigurator $container): void
    {
        $container->import(sprintf('%s/config/{packages}/*.{php,yaml}', $this->getProjectDir()));
        $container->import(sprintf('%s/config/{packages}/%s/*.{php,yaml}', $this->getProjectDir(), (string) $this->environment));

        $container->import(sprintf('%s/config/{services}/*.php', $this->getProjectDir()));
        $container->import(sprintf('%s/config/{services}/%s/*.php', $this->getProjectDir(), (string) $this->environment));
    }

    protected function configureRoutes(RoutingConfigurator $routes): void
    {
        $routes->import(sprintf('%s/config/{routes}/%s/*.{php,yaml}', $this->getProjectDir(), (string) $this->environment));
        $routes->import(sprintf('%s/config/{routes}/*.{php,yaml}', $this->getProjectDir()));
    }

    protected function build(ContainerBuilder $container): void
    {
        $container->registerForAutoconfiguration(CommandHandlerInterface::class)
            ->addTag('messenger.message_handler', ['bus' => 'command.bus'])
        ;
    }
}
```